# How to find a Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

I have lost my Magic Mouse. To be clear, it's somewhere in my home office and it's powered on. I can pair with it via bluetooth. I just can't find the physical object. Does anyone know of a way to make it beep or flash or something so I can locate it?

Comment: Note: I've run "system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType" and got RSSI = -63. That implies that the mouse is in the room. I'm not sure how to get closer. My keyboard is right next to my laptop (6 inches away) and has an RSSI of -48.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Magic Mouse has no such functionality.

If you have a cat, check its bed.

If you have a couch, check between and behind the cushions.

If you have a messy computer desk, (like mine,) give it a clean.

Could somebody have hidden it to play a prank on you? Check coat pockets, cookie jars, inside shoes, on top of bookcases....

It'll be in the place you least suspect it to be, and when you find it you'll remember that's right where you put it.

I once 'lost' an iPad Mini. It was with a stack of other iPad Minis in a horizontal file cabinet drawer, but it had cunningly secreted itself in a mostly invisible slot in the front of the drawer itself.

Comment: Update: I found it. I was hoping to avoid the drastic solution, cleaning up my office, but sometimes you have to bring out the big guns. My mouse slipped into the 2" gap between the desk and the wall. I used a combination of the iPhone camera, a flashlight, and a drafting straight edge to find it and fish it out. Thank you all for your support in this most trying of times.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post today and it really helped. Hopefully it works for others too..

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251049921

Comment: Hello, Pradeep Thaleppady. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.